# setting initializer (init) in a subclass swift

Tags: ios, swift, init, initializer

I'm trying to understand how to call from another class for example `let creation = menuButtonController(image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "maps"))` then in `menuButtonController`i set this:

```
class menuButtonController: UIView {

    let buttonView = UIView()
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    var imageButton: UIImageView


    init(frame: CGRect, image: UIImage) {
        super.init(frame: frame,image: image) //Cannot invoke  UIView.init with an argument list of type (frame cgrect, image uiimage)
        self.imageButton.image = image
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    /* other functions */
}
```

it give me a error that i'm not able to solve. can anyone helps me?

### Edit

now if i want to call only initializer with `(image: UIImage)` should i use a `convenience init` like this right?

```
convenience init(image: UIImage) {
    self.init(image: image)
    self.imageButton.image = image
}
```

it don't give me errors but crash when i try to run the application

Comment: Can you share what's the error that you get?

Comment: i write it in the comment inside the code. here's a copy: Cannot invoke  UIView.init with an argument list of type (frame cgrect, image uiimage)

Comment: Naming a subclass of `UIView` with a name of the form `xxxController` is a **terrible** idea. A view object and a controller object are totally different animals, and an object named `xxxController` should be a controller object, not a view object. Oh, and class names should start with an upper-case letter. So your class should be named something like `MenuButtonView`

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `init(frame: CGRect, image: UIImage)` in the super class `UIView`. You need to initialize `imageButton` first and call the designated initializer `init(frame`:

```
init(frame: CGRect, image: UIImage) {
    self.imageButton.image = image
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
```

By the way: Class names are supposed to start with capital letter.

Comment: ...and a view object should not have a name that ends with "Controller"...

Comment: now it show me a error: property self.imagebutton not initializer at super.init call (class changed in Menubutton

Comment: Yes, I wrote *You need to initialize `imageButton` first*

Comment: ok thank you, i have another question. if i want only to call a initializer with image: UIImage? (see Edit in the main post)

Comment: You have to call a (designated) initializer in the super class in any case or a convenience initializer which calls an appropriate initializer in the super class.